# Unable to make a http get request to SO

Tags: http, http-status-code-403

I have a piece of code in python that can make http get requests.
I can successfully make request to URL like http://google.com and download their page. But I can't make a get request to http://stackoverflow.com . It shows HTTP 403 forbidden ERROR. 
However I can access stackoverflow from my browser. So what could be the reason for this error?

**code:**

import urllib2
c=urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/')
contents=c.read()
print contents[0:50]

**error:**
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: `I have a piece of code in python` it's very hard for us to guess what your coe does without seeing it.

Comment: As the others have said, helps to see the code or at least the exact URL on SO that you are making the request from.  Does the request require auth?  Or does the http request automatically redirect to https?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same here, I'm using Python 3.

`urllib.request.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')` failed with HTTP error 403.

I changed User-Agent, and then it worked:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request('http://stackoverflow.com/',headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}))
```

So it seems stackoverflow.com filters requests based on User-Agent, and google.com doesn't do so.

> urllib2‘s default user agent string is "Python-urllib/2.6" (on Python
>   2.6)

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html